# NodeJS timer async without stopping the code and not using setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to call a function in NodeJS which checks `Date.Now` continuously if a flag is set to true.

I cannot use `setInterval` because it is too inaccurate.

My function works fine, but I want to call the function without blocking the whole code, so I thought an async method would do the job, but it isn't:

```js
var bufferLogRunning = true;
var dn_counter;
var masterbuffer_cache_log = [];

async function f() {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('FUNCION CALLED')
    var start = Date.now();
    while (bufferLogRunning == true) {
      if (dn_counter != Date.now() - start && dn_counter != undefined) {
        masterbuffer_cache_log.push({
          "millis": dn_counter,
          "buffer": "masterbuffer_cache"
        })
      }
      dn_counter = Date.now() - start
      if (Date.now() - start >= 4000) {
        bufferLogRunning = false;
      }
    }
    console.log('DONE')
    resolve("done!")
  });
  let result = await promise;
}

console.log('FIRST')
f();
console.log('SECOND')
```

How do I execute `console.log('SECOND')` while `f()` is running in background?

Comment: `I cannot use setInterval because it is too inaccurate. ` even if you use an interval that is smaller than the interval you actually want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `async` function does not magically convert code into something that does not block. It is just syntactic sugar to work with `Promise`s.

What you can do is to use [setImmediate](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args)

> Schedules the "immediate" execution of the callback after I/O events' callbacks.

And wrap that into a Promise:

```
function pause() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setImmediate(resolve)
   })
}
```

and call that function in your `while` loop, and use `await` to interrupt the execution of your `while` loop until the promise returned by `pause` resolves.

And using `new Promise((resolve, reject)` in your code does not make any sense

```
var bufferLogRunning = true;
var dn_counter;
var masterbuffer_cache_log = [];

async function f() {

  console.log('FUNCION CALLED')
  var start = Date.now();
  while (bufferLogRunning == true) {

    await pause(); // interrupt the execution to let I/O events happen 

    if (dn_counter != Date.now() - start && dn_counter != undefined) {
      masterbuffer_cache_log.push({
        "millis": dn_counter,
        "buffer": "masterbuffer_cache"
      })
    }
    
    dn_counter = Date.now() - start
    if (Date.now() - start >= 4000) {
      bufferLogRunning = false;
    }
  }
  console.log('DONE')

  let result = "done!"
}

console.log('FIRST')
f();
console.log('SECOND')
```

If `setImmediate` won't work in your use-case, you could replace it with`setTimeout`.

Comment: That worked like charm! Thank you very much and I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code from my program, with inline comments. Please have a look

```js
// Your app
const APP = {
  //
  // Cycle
  //
  cycle: (cb, timeout = 1e3, times = false) => {
    const start = Date.now();
    let i = 0;
    // Set delay method
    const delay = ms => {
      i++;
      // Check if stop enabled, then return immediately
      if(delay.stopTrigger || times && i > times) return true;
      // Run function
      const now = Date.now();
      const diff = now - start - i * timeout;
      // Run callback
      cb(now);
      // Set new timeout
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Compensate diff
        // We will compensate delay to
        // make it more accurate 
        delay(timeout-diff);
      }, ms);
    };
    // Set stop method
    delay.stopTrigger = false;
    delay.stop = () => delay.stopTrigger = true;
    // Run cycle with timeout
    setTimeout(delay, timeout, timeout);
    // Return delay object
    return delay;
  },
  
  //
  // Sync timeout function
  //
  timeout: ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)),
  
  //
  // !!!
  //
  // Your logic
  //
  init: async () => {
    // Start some cycle task for 500ms
    // First param is your function,
    // Second (optional/1000ms) - the delay amount in ms,
    // Third (optional/infinite) - cycles number
    const task = APP.cycle(now => {
      // Lets print something in a loop
      console.log(`Cycle task ${now}`);
    }, 500);
    
    // Now task holds stop method so we
    // can stop our cycle from this scope
    // But for now lets do some sync work
    
    // Sleep for 3 sec
    await APP.timeout(3000);
    
    // Print something
    console.log(`Hello from caller!`);
    
    // Sleep for 3 sec
    await APP.timeout(3000);
    
    // Print something and stop cycle
    console.log(`Hello from caller again and stop cycle now!`);
    task.stop();
    
    // Sleep for 3 sec
    await APP.timeout(3000);
    
     // Print something at the end
    console.log(`Hello from caller! All work done, exit now ;)`);
  }
};

// Run app
APP.init();
```